# Node.js $http PUT request returns nothing to server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, put, meanjs

I am working on an app that manages customer information. I am new to the MEAN stack, and can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong here. When I click on "Update Customer" from the view, the console prints the updated information, however when I attempt to send that information to the server and update my table I get nothing at all. The Customer entity just remains the same that it was before.

the view

```
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="addButton" style="padding: 10px;" >
<button 
  class="btn btn-primary" 
  ng-click="update()" 
  ng-disabled="editCustomerForm.$invalid">Update Customer</button>
```

the controller

```
    $scope.update = function(){
  console.log($scope.existingCustomer);
  $http.put('/customers/' + $scope.existingCustomer._id, $scope.existingCustomer).success(function(response) {
  refresh(); 
  $scope.existingCustomer={};
  $scope.editOldCustomer = false;
  })  
 };
```

server.js file

```
app.put('/customers/:id', function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
var id = req.params.id
db.customers.findAndModify({
query: {_id: "mongojs.ObjectId(id)"},
update: {$set: {name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, phone: req.body.phone,
                street: req.body.street, city: req.body.city, state: req.body.state, zip: req.body.zip}},
new: true}, function (err, doc) {
  res.json(doc);
}
 );
});
```

I have been wracking my brain with this for a few hours and just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it. Sorry if the formatting of some of the code got messed up on stack

Comment: What client or ORM are using to interact with your MongoDB instance?

Comment: I installed monogojs via sudo npm mongojs install

Comment: the git repo is https://github.com/jpstearns/customerApp

Answer (score 1):

You're issue looks to be here: `query: {_id: "mongojs.ObjectId(id)"},` where you're not actually creating an id, where you should probably do something like this: `var _id = mongojs.ObjectId(id);` and then use it like this: `{query: {_id: _id},`

Comment: that worked but now my app wont display the customer info in the input textboxes...

Comment: nevermind errors were completely unrelated thanks app running perfectly now

Comment: I wanted to mark this as the right answer but I dont see the check mark they are talking about thanks so much for the help